# Do I need to create schema.xml when creating a new core in Solr?

Tags: solr

I am running Solr 5.3.0 and I have created a new core using the command bin/solr create -c collection1.

However, I noticed there is no schema.xml file anywhere for that core in the collection1/conf folder.

Do I need to create the schema.xml from scratch each time I create a new core?

What is the best way to do this? Copy the one from {SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/solr/configsets\basic_configs\conf and modify the schema.xml to suit my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Solr 5.3 by default will create a managed schema without a schema.xml; you will then need to create everything you need in it via REST calls to Solr. You can read more about it [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API).

If you wanted to have the actual schema file you will need to create your collection like so:

bin/solr create -c collection1 -d {SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs

You can learn more about the options to create a collection by doing:

bin/solr create_collection help

Comment: -d can set a custom config folder, not necessarily an example config folder. to create a "core" rather than a "collection", we can use create_core command e.g. bin/solr create_core -c my_core_name -d /var/config/my_core_config. Besides, there's no schema.xml file since Solr 5.5. One have to copy mananged_schema to a new file named schema.xml, then do necessary modification.

Answer (score 2):

Solr  5 creates schema automatically for you and it is known as managed schema
In case you need to specify your own schema then you can use the below curl command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"order_count", "type":"int", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}'
```

name : the name of your column or field

type : data type of field

Similarly you can run curl commands for all the fields
You can run this command after creating your solr collection using solr create -c  command